# Is plus sign in +process a typo in Node.js documentation on domains?

Tags: node.js

In this documentation ...

http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html

... this line occurs:

```
var PORT = +process.env.PORT || 1337;
```

Is the plus sign a typo?  If not, what does it indicate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plus sign is a unary operator, and it coerces `process.env.PORT` to an number from a string.

Background:

```
// since all env variables are strings
process.env.PORT = 'somePortSavedAsSTring';
```

`process.env.PORT` must be a string and if nothing is done node will throw an error. Using the `+` sign prevents this from happening by essentially adding the string, ( which changes it from a string to a number ) to nothing.

```
port = ( nothing ) + 'somePortSavedAsSTring'; // makes it a number!

// whitespace is removed by convention, so other programmers know the intent
port = +'somePortSavedAsSTring';
```

Using the plus sign is this way is just an eloquent way to ensure the variable's type. You could use:

```
var PORT = Number(process.env.PORT) || 1337;
```

and get the exact same effect. It all just depends on your coding style at the end of the day.