# Plus operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

What does `if (t == +t) { ... }` mean?

Sorry for asking such a simple question, but I have searched for "plus operator" and tried to evaluate it in javascript myself, but I cannot guess what the purpose is.

Comment: Implicit conversion to number.

Comment: Haha this is almost word for word the same as the duplicate question. That's pretty funny.

Comment: Also, that comparison is pretty useless - double equals will already do the conversion.

Comment: @Vld: it's not useless - it will check if `t` can be converted to numeric type

Comment: @Adassko actually you're right - I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Its a [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Unary_operators) and it coerces `t` to a number from a string. It has the same effect as:

```
if (t == Number(t)) { ... }
```

For more information: [Is plus sign in +process a typo in Node.js documentation on domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751705/is-plus-sign-in-process-a-typo-in-node-js-documentation-on-domains/27751763#27751763)